# Any possibility of using KeyBlob (stored in byte format) for crypto operations

Tags: c, ubuntu, openssl

Created key blob using openssl. Now need to use that keyblob for crypto operations(like- encrypt, decrypt, signing and verifying) using openssl. So that code will be platform independent.

```
// Assume that "private_key" is having private key
// keyBlob is a byte array of size 2048
// e,n,p,q,dmp1,dmq1,iqmp,d are of type BIGNUM* and initialized with NULL    

RSA* rsa = new RSA( );

rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA ( private_key );
if ( NULL == rsa )
{
    hResult = errno;
    printf("\n\tError:EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA failed\n\n");
    break;
} // if
else
{
    //printf("\n\tRSA private key generated successfully\n\n");
} // else

e = rsa->e;
n = rsa->n;
p = rsa->p;
q = rsa->q;
dmp1 = rsa->dmp1;
dmq1 = rsa->dmq1;
iqmp = rsa->iqmp;
d = rsa->d;
version = rsa->version;

// Convert from bignum to binary.
// Modulus (n)
modulus = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(n, modulus);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Exponent1 (dmp1)
exponent1 = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(dmp1, exponent1);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Exponent2 (dmq1)
exponent2 = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(dmq1, exponent2);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Prime1 (p)
prime1 = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(p, prime1);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Prime2 (q)
prime2 = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(q, prime2);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Public exponent (e)
public_exponent = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(e, public_exponent);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Private exponent (d)
private_exponent = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));
iResult = BN_bn2bin(d, private_exponent);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

// Coefficient (iqmp)
coefficient = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(rsa), sizeof(unsigned char));

iResult = BN_bn2bin(iqmp, coefficient);
if( !iResult )
{
   hResult = errno;
   printf("\n\tError:BN_bn2bin failed\n\n");
   break;
} // if

RSAPUBKEY* rsapubkey = (RSAPUBKEY*)(keyBlob + sizeof(BLOBHEADER));

rsapubkey->bitlen = MAX_CERT_LEN;
rsapubkey->magic = 0x32415352; // 0x0032a400
rsapubkey->pubexp = *public_exponent;

int m1 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 8 + 20; 

unsigned int i  = 0;

// Convert all the components from Big Endian to Little Endian 
for( i = 0; i < (rsapubkey->bitlen / 8); i++)
{
    keyBlob[m1 - 1 - i] = modulus[i];
} // for

int p1 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 + m1;

for ( i = 0; i < ( rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 ); i++ )
{
    keyBlob[p1 - 1 - i] = prime1[i];
} // for

int p2 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 + p1;

for( i = 0; i < (rsapubkey->bitlen / 16); i++)
{
    keyBlob[p2- 1 - i] = prime2[i];
} // for

int e1 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 + p2;

for( i = 0; i < (rsapubkey->bitlen / 16); i++)
{
    keyBlob[e1 - 1 - i] = exponent1[i];
} // for

int e2 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 + e1;

for ( i = 0; i < ( rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 ); i++)
{
    keyBlob[e2 - 1 - i] = exponent2[i];
} // for

int c1 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 16 + e2;

for ( i = 0; i < (rsapubkey->bitlen / 16); i++ )
{
    keyBlob[c1 - 1 - i] = coefficient[i];
} // for

int d1 = rsapubkey->bitlen / 8 + c1;

for ( i = 0; i < (rsapubkey->bitlen / 8); i++ )
{
    keyBlob[d1 - 1 - i] = private_exponent[i];
} // for

/*
    FYI
    struct _RSAPUBKEY {
            DWORD   magic;                  // Has to be RSA1
            DWORD   bitlen;                 // # of bits in modulus
            DWORD   pubexp;                 // public exponent
                                            // Modulus data follows
    } RSAPUBKEY

    and 

    struct _PUBLICKEYSTRUC {
            BYTE    bType;
            BYTE    bVersion;
            WORD    reserved;
            ALG_ID  aiKeyAlg;
    } BLOBHEADER, PUBLICKEYSTRUC;
*/    
these structures already in wincrypt.h(in windows), but for linux we need add manually..
```

Here keyblob stored in "keyBlob".
Up to here its working fine.
Now in another function how to use this keyBlob for crypto operations(using rsa api).
Lets say we are using RSA_public_encrypt for encryption

Comment: Show your code and state the problem you are having.

Comment: please check above edited description

Comment: What is the the problem you are having? Would you please state a real problem, and not a hypothetical one? You also need to show `RSAPUBKEY` and `BLOBHEADER` structures.

Comment: I have added those structures. My problem is to know the procedure of using keyblob(created) for crypto operation like i said in the above description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the expected way to covert these ...

```
RSA* rsa = new RSA( );
...

e = rsa->e;
n = rsa->n;
p = rsa->p;
q = rsa->q;
dmp1 = rsa->dmp1;
dmq1 = rsa->dmq1;
iqmp = rsa->iqmp;
```

... to a byte arrays is to use [`BN_num_bytes` and `BN_bn2bin`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html):

```
int len, res;

len = BN_num_bytes(n);
unsigned char* n_arr = OpenSSL_malloc(len);
ASSERT(n_arr != NULL);
res = BN_bn2bin(n, n_arr);
ASSERT(res == len);

len = BN_num_bytes(e);
unsigned char* e_arr = OpenSSL_malloc(len);
ASSERT(e_arr != NULL);
res = BN_bn2bin(e, e_arr);
ASSERT(res == len);

...

OpenSSL_free(n_arr);
OpenSSL_free(e_arr);
```

Note the byte arrays are big endian.

You also need to free the `EVP_PKEY*` and the `RSA*`. The `1` in `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` means the reference count on the `RSA*` is bumped, so it needs a call to `RSA_free`. A `0` means the count was not incremented, so no `*_free` is required.

---

> Lets say we are using `RSA_public_encrypt` for encryption...

Use the `RSA*` directly.

> `RSAPUBKEY* rsapubkey = (RSAPUBKEY*)(keyBlob + sizeof(BLOBHEADER));`

If this is MS-CAPI, then you need to [reverse the byte arrays](http://www.google.com/search?q=MS-CAPI+reverse+byte+array+openssl). But its not clear to me its MS-CAPI.

I'm guessing your problem is the way the `BN` is extracted and converted. But its  just a guess because its not clear to me what you are trying to do other than to "use it".

Comment: No its not MS-CAPI. I'm trying these using openssl. so that code will work in any platform.

Comment: Also here as you said we can use RSA* directly if we performing encryption in the same function. But we are doing operation in other function (by passing keyblob and data as parameters)